# Can "as well as" be a conjunction?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

Can *as well as* be a conjunction that connects two independent sentences?
The reference to the relevant rules and similar threads would be much appreciated.

> The training program will be introduced more easily, *if
>   the video materials are offered, **as well as** it is possible to involve skillful specialists demonstrating response strategies in practice*.

Comment: There have been many other [questions involving this expression](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=as+well+as) here. A Norwegian university hosts [this article](http://site.uit.no/english/grammar/aswellas/) on the English phrase. And though it *is* a conjunction of sorts, it is not one to link two whole *clauses* as in your example.

Comment: *@Brian makes a good point, as well as I completely agree*. The cited usage (and my simpler version) are *not* "valid".

Comment: @Brian Donovan thanks. Which conjunction should be used in this example? _If_ should be a part of each clause in italics.

Comment: @user128024: What exactly is the relationship (and between *which elements*) that you want to express? Probably just ***and*** is all you need, but you should think about rearranging the sequence... *The training program will be introduced more easily, **and** it will be possible to involve skillful specialists demonstrating response strategies in practice, if the video materials are offered.* Note that you should echo the first ***will be***, not switch to ***is** possible*, for consistency. Also, the ***if*** clause can equally well appear at the start (but not *between* the "and" clauses).

Comment: Yes, *and* would do nicely. If you want to go with two *if* clauses, I would suggest *if the video materials are offered, and if skillful specialists demonstrate response strategies in practice.* (If it is merely *possible* to involve such demonstration, but none in fact takes place, then the mere possibility surely does not result in the training program's being introduced more easily.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers the' _will be_ ' part relates only to the program, the' _if_ 'parts should be in both clauses in italics (specialists and video). Thank you both!@Brian Donovan

Answer (score -1):

That particular usage sounds awkward but yes, it is a perfectly usable conjunction.

Comment: I think it's somewhat worse than "awkward". For me, ***as well as*** simply doesn't work for conjoining two fully-formed *statements*. I'm not a complete pedant (some of [the usage restrictions here](http://site.uit.no/english/grammar/aswellas/) go beyond what many competent native speakers would honour in normal conversation), but I don't think learners should be told that the cited example is "acceptable". It's not.